# Preventing PHP SQL injection on login

Tags: php, sql, mysql, sql-injection

I had a login code like this:

```
$jmeno = $_POST['jmeno'];
$heslo = $_POST['heslo'];

$sql = mysqli_query($pripojeni, "SELECT jmeno, heslo FROM databaze WHERE jmeno = '$jmeno'");
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $db_jmeno = $data['jmeno'];
    $db_heslo = $data['heslo'];
}

if ($jmeno == $db_jmeno AND $heslo == password_verify($heslo, $db_heslo)){
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
    $_SESSION['jmeno'] = $jmeno;
```

And I found on the internet that having a user variable in sql command is really bad idea.

I read something about pdo and preparing, executing statements and I changed the code to this:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($PDO_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Připojení selhalo: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$priprava = $pdo->prepare("SELECT jmeno, heslo FROM databaze WHERE jmeno = ?");
$priprava->execute([$jmeno]);
$uzivatel = $priprava->fetch();

if ($uzivatel && password_verify($_POST['heslo'], $uzivatel['heslo']))
{
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
    $_SESSION['jmeno'] = $jmeno;
```

Can you please just tell me if this is correctly done and much better for SQL injection?

Thank you.

-------- Second code (for example and my know)

In other script I have it like this:

```
$id = $_GET['polozka'];

$pripojeni = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST,$DATABASE_USER,$DATABASE_PASS,$DATABASE_NAME);
mysqli_set_charset($pripojeni, "utf8mb4");

$vysledek = mysqli_query($pripojeni,"SELECT hra, polozka, pouzito FROM databaze WHERE id = '$id'");
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vysledek)) {
        
        $hra = $data['hra'];
        $polozka = $data['polozka'];
        $uplatneno = $data['pouzito'];
        
    }
```

I guess this code is also really bad so I changed it to this:

```
$dotaz = $pdo->prepare("SELECT hra, polozka, pouzito FROM databaze WHERE id = ?");
$dotaz->execute([$id]);
$podpora_inventar = $dotaz->fetch();
$hra = $podpora_inventar['hra'];
$polozka = $podpora_inventar['polozka'];
$uplatneno = $podpora_inventar['pouzito'];
```

is it ok like that?

Comment: @YourCommonSense wants you to learn this: https://phpdelusions.net/delusion/try-catch Additional reading: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271699/pdo-is-try-catch-necessary-or-not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11271699/2943403) and [Why does this PDO statement silently fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32648371/2943403)

Comment: We are going to have problems reviewing the code because it isn't English. It would also be better if you provided all the code in the file as it appears in the file, it is very difficult to review snippets. We don't need to see your old code just the code that is working now.

Answer (score 1):

## let exceptions bubble up

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($PDO_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS);
    ...
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Připojení selhalo: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Maybe you wrote down a Requirement in your user story
so the program *has* to exhibit this behavior,
in which case this is perfect as-is.
But I suspect not.
Notice that we don't really "handle" (repair / ignore)
the error. We merely report it.

Rather than `try` / `catch` / `die`,
just connect to the database and if an exception happens,
it happens. Let it bubble up the call stack.
If some higher-level caller wants to catch it
and do something useful, great.
If by default we print out an informative diagnostic stack trace,
also great.
Much more helpful than the one-liner you currently offer.

Maybe you have this connected to a web server.
Which serves random folks you wouldn't want to trust.
If so, consider writing down some Security requirements.
Like not revealing many code or data details.
Here, you might prefer to just say, "You lose! Send
email to support for assistance.", rather than revealing
the particular DB diagnostic.

## extract helper

```
    $pdo = new PDO($PDO_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

These three lines
would fit very nicely into a helper named `get_db_connection`,
following [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).
Maybe you re-use the code when there's multiple
callers of that helper. Maybe you don't.
Doesn't matter. **Naming** a chunk of code is
valuable to future maintainers, including yourself.
Cultivate that habit.

## injection fixed

```
$priprava = $pdo->prepare("SELECT jmeno, heslo FROM databaze WHERE jmeno = ?");
$priprava->execute([$jmeno]);
$uzivatel = $priprava->fetch();
```

Looks good to me, ship it!
This is the correct way to send in query parameters,
much better than the unquoted string interpolation you had before.

I am accustomed to more compact idioms for sending a query,
so I'm slightly surprised it takes three lines in this environment.
Well, it is what it is.
Recommend you package this up as another tiny helper,
passing in at least a query string and a query value.
You might also pass in `$pdo`, but your class might be
able to find it as an object attribute, in which case use that.

Notice that we must test the `fetch()` return value,
which you correctly do.
Consider making it slightly more convenient for app-level code to call your
helper and correctly consume what it returns.
That is, consider putting the test within the helper,
and throw an exception upon seeing an unexpected DB result.

You return `jmeno` / `username`.
Possibly it's convenient during debugging.
But it's not strictly necessary; consider eliding it.

## use hashed passwords

Yay, you win! You're doing it right.
And there's even a salt incorporated in there, which is appropriate.
I am reading the
[documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

> password_verify(string $password, string $hash):

```
if ($uzivatel && password_verify($_POST['heslo'], $uzivatel['heslo']))
```

I was having a hard time reading that line,
and it didn't look right to me.
It turns out that technically it is correct, but
it's not terrific at communicating your intent to collaborators.

It ends with `$user['password']))`, which made me nervous.
Turns out the code is lying, as this is definitely not a
cleartext password. Please choose a better identifier,
maybe `zpravaSouhrn`, `messageDigest`,
`povereni`, `credential`, or `passwordHash`.

An identifier like `uzivatel` or `user` is fine as it is.
But think of the conventional idiom of `for i in ...`.
Often the best name for an index is `i`.
Here, you might find it convenient to conventionally
talk about a `radek` or `row` that came back from
the database, letting the query context advise us
that it's a row from the user database.

## table encodings should match

```
mysqli_set_charset($pripojeni, "utf8mb4");
```

Oh, my! Haven't seen that one before. We have left the
[BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)
behind. I imagine you're storing U+1F602  and similar emojis.
And you need O(1) constant time indexing to an offset,
which ordinary UTF8 can't accommodate.
I'm sure you're doing the right thing, here.

As a reminder, for both mysql and postgres it is important
to use consistent on-disk encodings.
That is, if you ever plan to JOIN tables A and B
in a performant way, you want the rows and the indexes
to all use the identical encoding and collation scheme.
A mismatch may prevent the backend planner from
exploiting an index, impacting performance.

So if the four-byte `utf8mb4` encoding is
your standard, good, so be it.
For a table with lots of Czech text (BMP text)
I wonder if, like utf32, that will consume a bunch more disk blocks
than utf8 does.

Oh, wait, now I am reading the
[documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php),
this is frightening.

> MySQL's utf8 encoding has a maximum of 3 bytes and is unable to encode *all* unicode characters.

Wow! I had no idea.
Guess I've been using Postgres mostly.
It would never occur to me that "utf8" would
denote something different from
[the spec](https://www.unicode.org/glossary/#UTF_8).
Looks like you do have to do that.
A unit test which INSERTs and SELECTs an emoji would be helpful.

## be boring

Choosing "boring" identifiers is actually a good thing.
For example, choosing the identical names that your
library's documentation uses makes your code easier to read.
It helps us to trace provenance,
and it asserts that "foo" over here is identical to "foo" over there, having the same semantics.
Letting a DB column name dictate the
naming of a local variable is another
variation on the same theme.

```
        $uplatneno = $data['pouzito'];
```

Yes, I get it that there's more than one synonym for "applied".

Here, I recommend you assign `$pouzito = ...`,
in the interest of readability for future maintainers.

And see above, where your deliberate use
of `heslo` and `heslo` threw me for a loop,
since they have *very* different semantics there.

---

This codebase would benefit from the addition
of one or more unit tests.

I would be willing to delegate maintenance tasks
on this codebase to engineers who are proficient
at conversational Czech.
This codebase is not currently suited to
maintenance by a diverse international team.

> is it ok like that?

Yes, [LGTM](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/lgtm),
merge down to `main`.

Comment: Thank you very much for all of this. I will read it more times because it is containing so much technical stuff and english as you see and know is not my native language, but it will help me so much. Thank you once again. The charset is already gone now. I had issues with some Czech letters, but it was my bad formating. My top priority is the SQL injections that I have got with the old code and the hacker read everything in the database because of that (I think/guess).

Comment: Oh. If there was a DB exposure then your hashes are [public knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack). Make a snapshot of them. Reset all passwords to something new. After some days go by, compare current hashes with the snapshot. You will find that some are unchanged. Disable / delete all such unchanged accounts, as they are compromised. Recreate such accounts with new passwords as the need arises. This is just standard procedure for dealing with a breach. Also, don't be surprised if a single compromised account allowed the intruder to expand to other internal systems.

Comment: I have mixed feelings about this answer. It contains very good suggestions along with just... talking to yourself? Consider leaving only useful suggestions for the OP. I don't see how the "table encodings should match" section is one. and "use hashed passwords" as well.